# Is there an API to the GMail server?

Tags: gmail

[I know there's an API for a Gmail plugin in your browser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2819528/gmail-plugin-api-development). Is there one for the server? For example, if I want to write an anti-virus app that reads emails coming in to an account on the server, then let's them continue or quarantines them - all before the user ever sees them?

Obviously it would have to be authorized for the users it did this for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

EDIT: As of 26/06/2014, this answer has become incorrect, as Google just released a dedicated API to GMail. See the link in [this post for reference](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24417419/1680196).

Original answer below this line :

---

From a technological perspective, it's a mail server just like any other.

Thus, your choice should fall on a mail protocol. It's also already answered in the question you linked: https://stackoverflow.com/a/2820280/1680196

Your app would open an IMAP connection to your mail server of choice (in this case gmail), scan for incoming mail, read the content and trigger a delete / move to trash if necessary.

Personally, I wouldn't trust any app like this running outside my own mailserver / mail client, since this use case requires full read and write access to a users mails.

There might be some API for Google Apps for Domains mail accounts, but I doubt this goes beyond the RSS mail notifications.

Edit: Official Google api documentation also refers to IMAP for accessing user inboxes. [Link to IMAP OAuth overview](https://developers.google.com/gmail/oauth_overview). With application specific passwords users could enable your app to access their account without exposing their actual credentials, but beyond that I fear you are out of luck.

Answer (score 1):

There is an HTTP REST API now!
http://developers.google.com/gmail/api/
(And has been for years if you were willing to use IMAP. :-D)